# How to open new tab in python using selenium and PhantomJS

Tags: python, selenium, tabs, phantomjs

Setting up an automated browser test in Python 3.4 and am using the headless browser - phantomjs.

The usual way of opening a new tab (Keys.CONTROL + 't') is not working for phantomjs. I assume there is either a method in selenium I could use, or a specific key combination for phantomjs to open a tag, however I cannot find it. I could use chrome, or firefox however I want PhantomJS only.

I need a new tab because I will keep two tabs open and switch between windows via:

handles = driver.window_handles
driver.switch_to.window(handles[0])

The problem with phantomjs, is that it doesn't create a new tab and thus, only one handle.

anyone know?

Comment: are you running on Mac by any chance? If so, try replacing CONTROL by COMMAND, other than that it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, way late on an answer to this... but one thing to keep in mind is PhantomJS is a headless browser. There are no "tabs" such as what you see in Firefox, Chrome, etc. What you want to do is open a new window, which can only really be done with `execute_script`. For example, if you run the following, you'll get a good sense of how window's work in Selenium:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://linkedin.com")
driver.execute_script("$(window.open('https://twitter.com'))")
print driver.current_window_handle

# Switch to new window
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
print " Twitter window should go to facebook "
print "New window ", driver.title
driver.get("http://facebook.com")
print "New window ", driver.title

# Switch to old window
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
print " Linkedin should go to gmail "
print "Old window ", driver.title
driver.get("http://gmail.com")
print "Old window ", driver.title

# Again new window
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
print " Facebook window should go to Google "
print "New window ", driver.title
driver.get("http://google.com")
print "New window ", driver.title
```

Comment: Got this error when tried your code though `"errorMessage":"Can't find variable: $"` which caused by this line, `driver.execute_script("$(window.open('https://twitter.com'))")`